# What is connection between Pearson correlation coefficient and proportion of variance explained in PCA?

Tags: regression, pca, dimensionality-reduction

PCA procedure includes SVD of Covariance matrix. Based on eigenvalues we can find a proportion of variance explained by related Principal Components (eigenvectors).

`variance explained by PC1 (in case symmetric matrix) = eigenvalue1 / (sum of all eigenvalues) * 100%`

We form a covariance matrix as `[ [SD1^2, RO*SD1*SD2], [RO*SD1*SD2, SD2^2]]`
(SD = standard deviation, RO = Pearson correlation coefficient)

It is clear that if RO = 1 then PC1 explains ~100% of the variance.

Can you please suggest intuition and a general (mathematical) connection between Pearson correlation coefficient and proportion of variance explained in PCA?